# Exporting SQL Server Blob field to file via SAS

Tags: sql-server, sas

I am working on a SAS interface to export pictures stored within SQL Server as blob fields via SAS. My problem is trying to get SAS to not 'fiddle' with the data in between reading it from the DB and writing it to a file.

So far I've been able to retrieve an image and write it to a file with a file size *approximately* correct (ie within 100 bytes), consequently when I try displaying the resulting image file it is corrupted.

If I diff a working picture with the generated one, it looks like some lines have had a newline inserted in them and caused the corruption. As a test, if I try to manually correct these line glitches then I can get the image to render on the screen, but it is visually corrupted.

My thinking is that the problem lies in the formats I am using to save the image, either in the put statement when I create the work table. I'm hoping that some SAS format guru can help me out here....

```
LIBNAME sphoto ODBC <...omitted>  DBMAX_TEXT=32767;

proc sql noprint;
    create table work.PHOTOS as
    SELECT
        photo as ImageData format=$32767. informat=$32767.
    FROM
        sphoto.Photos
    WHERE ...
    ;
quit;

data _null_;
    set work.PHOTOS;
    file "image_sas.jpg";
    put ImageData;
run;
```

UPDATE

See comment below, changed the file statement to this and it is working now.

`file "/home/221741D/cardax/image_sas.jpg" LRECL=32767 NOPRINT NOTAB;`

Comment: Got it! The trick was in the file statement. I had to tell SAS not to add carriage returns via the noprint flag. `file "image_sas.jpg" noprint lrecl=32767;`

Comment: I realize this is a little late, like 3.75 years late, but if you've answered your question then I suggest you submit an answer and accept it. That's how we do on SO.